# Compare the results of 2 dices in Python programming

Tags: python, c#, compare, dice

I take the liberty of writing on this forum to tell you about my difficulties in code. Indeed, I have a project to realize for my studies and I am starting in programming so I will need a little help.

So here is the goal of my project is to make a game in Object Oriented Programming in the Python language.

This game is based on luck. Let me explain, a player and a monster will " fight " with the help of dice draws. In fact, the one with the highest number wins the fight.
For example, if the player rolls the dice and gets the number "8" whereas the monster gets the number "6" then the monster loses his life. The same goes for the player.

I would like to make it clear that I did not invent this game, I found it on another site : https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/2818931-programmez-en-oriente-objet-avec-c/2818991-tp-creez-un-petit-jeu-oriente-objet

-> On the latter, the explanations are more complete and much more thorough. However, these explanations are in French.

My post is thus addressed to those who would retranscribe this program coded in C into a program coded in Python.

Or to those who would help me where I am. Indeed, from this stage there I created only the two classes "player" and "EasyMonster" and I encounter a problem.
At the moment of the die roll I would like the two draws (the player and the monster") **to compare**, **problem I don't see how to do it.** I tried (with a combat function) but without success.

To give you a more concrete example:
"The player has drawn the number 8", "The monster has drawn the number 4", the player then takes life points from the monster.

Here is my code:

```
    from random import*

class joueur():

    def __init__(self, NbreDeVie, NomDuPerso):
        self.vie=NbreDeVie
        self.nom=NomDuPerso

    def afficheEtat (self):
        print ("Il reste "+str(self.vie)+ " points de vie à " +self.nom)
        if self.vie == 0:
            print("Mario n'a plus de vie")

    def attaque (self):
        print(self.nom+ " veut attaquer "+ "monstre")


    def SubitDegats (self):
        print(self.nom + " subit des dégats de la part de " + "monstre" + " !")
        self.vie=self.vie-1

    def LanceleDe (self):
        self.LanceleDe
        tirage = randint(1,6)
        print(tirage)


Mario= joueur(150, "Mario")

#print(Mario.SubitDegats())

print("Le nombre tiré par notre joueur est")
print(Mario.LanceleDe())

#----------------------------

class MonstreFacile():

    def __init__(self,NbredeVie,NomduPerso): # on définit la méthode qui va initialiser les attributs
        self.vie=NbredeVie
        self.nom=NomduPerso


    def afficheEtat(self): #voici la méthode qui affiche l'état du personnage
        print ('Il reste '+str(self.vie)+' points de vie')

#OBJECTIF : Créer une méthode qui enlèvera un point de vie au personnage blesse, une méthode qui affichera le nombre de vies restantes

    def SubitDegats (self):#voici la méthode qui fait perdre 1 point de vie au personnage qui a subit une attaque
        print(self.nom + " subit des dégats de la part de " + "monstre" + " !")
        self.vie=self.vie-1


    def LanceleDe(self):
        self.LanceleDe
        tirage = randint(1,6)
        print(tirage)


# on crée une instance de la classe personnage nommée Bowser (plus d'indentation, car la définition de la classe est terminée)

Bowser=MonstreFacile(20,'Bowser') ##on crée l'instance Bowser sans oublier de passer le nombre de points de vie et le nom du personnage

print("Le nombre tiré par le monstre est")
print(Bowser.LanceleDe())

def combat(self):

    if Mario.LanceleDe >= Bowser.LanceleDe:
        Bowser.SubitDegats
```

If I have not been clear enough, don't hesitate to tell me, hoping that someone can help me!

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this post, have a nice day!

Comment: Why is this labeled C# when you want c?

Comment: @jdweng Excuse me, I forgot to mention the "#" and the site where I found the original code is also coded in C# to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was little hard for me to help you since i dont speak language. I belive you forgot to call method (you forgot the "()" at the name of method when calling it). I hope this is your solution, since i dont understand the language :). I belive this is your solution

```
from random import*

class joueur():

    def __init__(self, NbreDeVie, NomDuPerso):
        self.vie=NbreDeVie
        self.nom=NomDuPerso

    def afficheEtat (self):
        print ("Il reste "+str(self.vie)+ " points de vie à " +self.nom)
        if self.vie == 0:
            print("Mario n'a plus de vie")

    def attaque (self):
        print(self.nom+ " veut attaquer "+ "monstre")


    def SubitDegats (self):
        print(self.nom + " subit des dégats de la part de " + "monstre" + " !")
        self.vie=self.vie-1

    def LanceleDe (self):
        self.LanceleDe
        tirage = randint(1,6)
        return(tirage)


Mario= joueur(150, "Mario")

#print(Mario.SubitDegats())

print("Le nombre tiré par notre joueur est")
print(Mario.LanceleDe())

#----------------------------

class MonstreFacile():

    def __init__(self,NbredeVie,NomduPerso): # on définit la méthode qui va initialiser les attributs
        self.vie=NbredeVie
        self.nom=NomduPerso


    def afficheEtat(self): #voici la méthode qui affiche l'état du personnage
        print ('Il reste '+str(self.vie)+' points de vie')

#OBJECTIF : Créer une méthode qui enlèvera un point de vie au personnage blesse, une méthode qui affichera le nombre de vies restantes

    def SubitDegats (self):#voici la méthode qui fait perdre 1 point de vie au personnage qui a subit une attaque
        print(self.nom + " subit des dégats de la part de " + "monstre" + " !")
        self.vie=self.vie-1


    def LanceleDe(self):
        self.LanceleDe
        tirage = randint(1,6)
        return(tirage)


# on crée une instance de la classe personnage nommée Bowser (plus d'indentation, car la définition de la classe est terminée)

Bowser=MonstreFacile(20,'Bowser') ##on crée l'instance Bowser sans oublier de passer le nombre de points de vie et le nom du personnage

print("Le nombre tiré par le monstre est")
print(Bowser.LanceleDe())

def combat(self):

    if Mario.LanceleDe() >= Bowser.LanceleDe():
        Bowser.SubitDegats()
    elif Mario.LanceDe() < Bowser.LanceleDe():
        Mario.SubitDegats()

combat(1);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to study my programme despite the difficulty of comprehension, especially at the level of language. I know that it's quite difficult to understand a language you don't speak. For information I am French ;).

As for your code proposition, it's very interesting because I forgot to put the "()". However it still doesn't work as I want.

I would like the comparison of the results of the 2 dice to be written in the console.

Example: "Mario has a higher number than Bowser. Bowser loses his life."

Comment: try now. I belive this is what you have been looking for